# Resource based on objects in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, resource-files

In a separate project I have a de-serialized xml file with strings that I want to use in my WPF application, these strings are also used within a different project in the same solution, so I can't just move the strings over to the project holding the wpf application.

The program is structured like this:

**Project A** *references* B and C

- WPF application with event handlers

**Project B** *references* C

- GUI logic in F#

**Project C**

- XML resource file and de-serializer (written in F#)

Is there a way for me to make a resource or resource dictionary based on the objects from the deserialized xml file? or can I reference the strings stored in the xml file directly?

Comment: Is the deserialized object just a class with some string properties? You could simply make it a singleton then and directly access the properties. Why would you need a resource dictionary?

Comment: because it has to be accessed by 2 projects, making an xml file that dynamically gets deserialized is pretty easy to work with... that is if wpf would allow an easy way to include external resources

Comment: I am kind of confused here - why are you using XML for strings and not the resources option on project?

Comment: @ChandramouleswaranRavichandra would that work across multiple projects? or do I have to add the same resource on every project?

Comment: Yes that should work. See Borislav Ivanov's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I managed to do something that works like I intended, but instead of using the deserialized objects, I used the xml file itself.

Here's what I did:

First I changed the XML file's `Build Action` from `Content` to `Resource` by going `Right-click the file -> Properties -> Build Action -> Resource`
[image: The Build Action menu]

Then I went into the Xaml file, and added the following to `Window.Resources`

```
<XmlDataProvider 
    x:Key="DropDownData" 
    Source="/Resource;component/Strings.xml" 
    XPath="/Strings/String" />
```

In the drop-down menu that I needed the strings I added this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DropDownData}}"
```

And now my strings are beautifully displayed in the WPF gui.

Thanks for your suggestions though; they may come in useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the built-in .resx file, which is included by default in freshly created WPF application. (You can also add it at later time using `Project -> Add New Item... -> Resource File`.) Just be sure to set the access modifier to "Public" and you will be able to use the strings inside other projects that references the current one: 
[image: Public Resx File] 
You will be able to access strings (and other resources as well!) through a strongly-typed, automatically generated wrapper class:

```
MessageBox.Show(WpfApplication1.Properties.Resources.String1);
```

You can also set properties using XAML to the strings stored in this file, using the [x:Static markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx), as desribed in (for example) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7439615/259206):

```
xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Properties;assembly=WpfApplication1" 
Title="{x:Static resx:Resources.String1}"
```

Additionally you'll get nice, Visual Studio built-in, UI for editing the file (also visible in the picture).

Comment: there's one minor problem with your solution; the wpf project can't be seen by the f# project, so I won't be able to access it without referencing the wpf project in the f# project; but visual studio doesn't allow me to do that because the reference is already made the other way, I can't just make another wpf application for the resource alone either since I'd then have a window I'd never use...

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems your projects that will use the common resource strings will be implemented using WPF technology. In this case you could change a little the format of your xml and have directly a xaml file containing the serialized form of a ResourceDictionary. After that you can just deserialize your file and you have a ResourceDictionary. Serialization and deserialization can be done using the XamlWriter and XamlReader.

Code example:

```
        var pc = new ParserContext
        {
            BaseUri = new Uri(runtimeResourcesDirectory , UriKind.Absolute)
        };
        ...
        using (Stream s = File.Open(resourceDictionaryFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            try
            {
                var resourceDictionary = XamlReader.Load(s, pc) as ResourceDictionary;
                if (resourceDictionary != null)
                {
                    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid xaml: " + resourceDictionaryFile);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The tooling in F# project is not so good, so what I have suggested in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18904554/259206) won't work. 
In C# projects, there is custom tool named "ResXFileCodeGenerator" that is run (just before the build) over the .resx file and generates the C# wrapper class. This is obviosly not available in F# projects. You have to workarounds though. 
The easiest approach that comes to my mind - that is if you want to use the strongly typed wrapper generated from the C# custom tool - is to add new C# class library to your solution, which will contain the resx file and will generate the wrapper class. You can add the .resx file from `Project -> Add New Item... -> Resource File`. Then you can reference this library from all your F# projects and use the generated wrapper class:

```
open ClassLibrary1; // this is the C# library
...
let x = Resources.String1;
```

The second approach is to add a .resx file directly to your F# project. The funny thing here is that Visual Studio won't allow you to "Add new item" of type Resource. You can workaround this by creating Resource file in another, temporary project - for example of type C# class library, and then add the generated .resx file to your F# project using the `Project -> Add Existing Item` command. Then you can use the resources from the resx file using the [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Resources.ResourceManager%28v=vs.102%29.aspx) class (of course without the generated properties for every resources, as in the previous case):

```
open Library1
open System.Resources

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
// We are in the console application, which references Library1
// Library1 contains the .resx file.

let resourceManager = ResourceManager("Resources", typeof<Library1.Class1>.Assembly);

let x = resourceManager.GetString("String1");

0
```

Note that in the upper case I have added the resource file directly in the project (not in subfloder), as a file named Resources.resx. 
You can additionally create your custom wrapper which encapsulates such calls within properties.

Comment: why can't I just reference the objects I had created from the xml file? I mean it should be simple enough to just call the strings into the wpf project, thus saving me a lot of re-doing...