# How to set Property value from resources.resx file to Xamdatagrid Field name property

Tags: infragistics, xamdatagrid

I want to set Name value of the xamdatagrid field from properties Resources file

xamdatagrid field name property

Comment: <igDP:Field Name="Message">. I want to set the Name value from resources.resx file

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919367/get-values-from-resx-files-in-xaml), you can use the x:Static markup extension:

```
<igDP:Field Name="{x:Static res:ResourceFileName.FieldName}"
```

You will need to declare the res namespace:

```
xmlns:res="clr-namespace:TheNamespaceOfYourResxFile"
```

And change the Access Modifier of the resx file [to Public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274311/visual-studio-resx-file-default-internal-to-public)