# Access values from xaml file in the code(View) directly

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, resourcedictionary

I have a file (icons.xaml) that I added as a file in the Resources of my project. The file content is given below:

**Icons.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<VisualBrush x:Key="Bucket"
             Stretch="Uniform">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Viewbox Stretch="xxxx">
            <Canvas Width="xxxxx"
                    Height="xxxx"> and so on...
```

[Icons.xaml file's properties in vs 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB1aS.png)

Now, I want to consume the VisualBrush mentioned above, in my XAML (View) code directly. The lines are given below:

**XAML Code (View)**

```
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
       <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Bucket, Source={x:Static resx:Resources.Icons}}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The "resx" namespace is defined as:

```
xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:MyProjectNamespace.Properties"
```

When I run my project I cannot see my icons being binded to the rectangle's fill property and I am getting some xaml intellisense error which is "Cannot resolve property "Bucket" in the context of type "string".

**Objective: I want to use the visualbrush key directly in the XAML** in my Rectangle's Fill property in my View code.

Note: I have a restriction that I cannot use the code in the view  which is given below, I cannot use `<ResourceDictionary>` tab in the xaml code.

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProjectNamespace;component/Resources/Icons.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

Am I following the right approach regarding my objective or should I change this approach?

I have seen the methods that are used here in this answer but none of them are working [Get values from *.resx files in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919367/get-values-from-resx-files-in-xaml)

Comment: `icons.xaml` isn't a .resx file. what you need is StaticResource (or DynamicResource) `<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource Bucket}"/>`. but you have to load "icons" resource dictionary first into MergedDictionaries of your view in your xaml code

Comment: Ok, first I need to make it a resx file then I should carry on?. 
Because, I have a restriction to use Mergedictionary tabs (or words) in my xaml file

Comment: I thought you need access to VisualBrush, not .resx file. I suggested how to get it from ResourceDictionary.  "have a restriction to use Mergedictionary tabs (or words) in my xaml file" - no idea what this could mean

Comment: @ASh I have modified my question

Comment: Since you have a restriction to use Merged dictionaries, can you use local resources?

Comment: @LukášKoten I could use local resources.

Comment: <Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary 
    Source="/MyProjectNamespace;component/Resources/Icons.xaml"> 
 </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

and then, in same xaml: 
<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource Bucket}"/>

Comment: Did it helped to you?

Comment: @LukášKoten Sorry for the late reply. No it cannot as I cannot use the <ResourceDicionary> words in the xaml and secondly, I only have usercontrol not winodws

Comment: Well if you cannot use (for some reason) ResourceDictionary in xaml, you can still read them in code.

Comment: @LukášKoten Can i use this mergedDictionary in the code behind and use the resources in the xaml?

Comment: Sure, you can read from MergedDictionary in code behind to access the VisualBrush and assign it to control you want (Rectangle), all from code.

Comment: @LukášKoten could you provide code for this, if it works I will mark it as answer

Answer (score -1):

I think the main issue here is that Binding is actually looking for a property called Binding on the Resources.Icons object.

Try this:

```
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
       <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Bucket, Source={x:Static resx:Icons}}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: If I write your code in the xaml, I receive error on the on the "Icons" word, saying "cannot resolve symbol 'Icons'"

Answer (score -1):

Binding is not necessary, just try:

`<Rectangle Fill="{x:Static resx:Resources.Icons.Bucket}"/>`

Comment: Compile error "Cannot find the member "Bucket" on the target type".